# QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context

Tags: macos, opengl, x11

I am a new MacOS user. I have a problem when I ssh into a remote computer using X11 forwarding. I am trying to view 3D Slicer from my remote computer. 3D Slicer loads correctly, but I am unable to visualize anything. However, if I hover the mouse I can see the menu options. But I am unable to see any data that I load. 
On the terminal, I see QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context and 
composeAndFlush: QOpenGLContext creation failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed

I tried updating my MacOS in the hope that the driver would also update. But that did not help either.

I am using a Mac mini (Late 2014), macOS Catalina with a 2.6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 processor and Intel Iris Graphics.

Comment: It's likely you won't be able to do it. Few graphics drivers support OpenGL indirect rendering. Even Mesa on Xorg, which does support it, limits you to OpenGL 1.4 in this mode, which is useless for modern 3D apps.